# how to use the chi-square table

Tags: probability, statistics

can anyone explain me how to use the [chi-square distribution table](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~mga/401/tables/Chi-square-table.pdf) for a set of 2 types of elements with equal probability?

Comment: found the answer here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXPBoFDqNVk

Comment: No wonder you're having trouble. Apparently, this is the $wrong$ page of the chi-squared table for your purposes. Common mistake. See my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the chi-squared goodness-of-fit test for tossing a coin $n=100$ times.

**Hypothesis and Data.** Null hypothesis is "Coin Fair" or $p = P(Heads) = 1/2.$
Expected number of Heads is $np = 100(1/2) = 50.$

Also $1 - p = q = P(Tails) = 1 - 1/2 = 1/2.$
Expected number of Tails is $nq = 100(1/2) = 1/2.$

Suppose I conduct such an experiment. I have a coin that may
or may not be fair. I get 23 Heads and 100 - 23 = 72 Tails.
So observed values are 23 and 77.

**Computing the chi-squared statistic from a formula.**
Make a table to organize your computations:

```
               Category
           ----------------
 Counts    Heads      Tails    Total
 ----------------------------------- 
 Expected   50         50       100
 Observed   23         77       100

 O - E     -27         27         0
 Sq Dif    729        729       ---
 Contrib    14.58      14.58     29.16 = Chi-sq statistic
```

The formula for the chi-squared statistic is

$$Q = \sum_{i = 1}^k \frac{(O_i - E_i)^2}{E_i},$$
where $k$ is the number of categories (two here), $E_i$
are the expected counts, and $O_i$ are the observed counts.
(Some texts use $X_i$ for the observed counts.)
The two quantities that are summed are called the
"contributions" to the chi-squared statistic.

The better the fit of the data (observed counts) to the
model (represented by the expected counts), the $smaller$
the value of $Q$. So bad fit gives big values of $Q$.
(Maybe it should have been called a "$badness$ of fit statistic".)

**Using printed tables.** The chi-squared table gives cut-off values $c$. How big can
$Q$ be before we reject the model and say the coin is not fair?
The rows of the table show $df$ = 'degrees of freedom'; $df = k - 1,$
so here we look in the row labeled 1.
If we test at the 5% level of significance, the cut-off value
or 'critical value' is $c= 3.841.$ Because our value of $Q = 29.16 > c = 3.841$ you reject the null hypothesis that the coin is fair.
[Actually, our value of $Q$ is so large (the fit is so bad) that
you could also reject at lower significance percentages such as 1%.
Look in other columns of the (correct) table for critical values
associated with other significance levels.

**NOTE:** In the style of table you show
in your link (with areas in the right-hand tail of the distribution
as shaded in the figure) you want to look in the column headed
`o.o5` or `5%`. $You\; have\; the\; wrong\; page!$ You don't
want the column in this table headed `0.95`.

**Related printouts from statistical software.** Here is an analysis of my Heads/Tails data in Minitab statistical
software.

```
 Chi-Square Goodness-of-Fit Test for Observed Counts in Variable: Obs 

 Using category names in Cat


                           Test            Contribution
 Category  Observed  Proportion  Expected     to Chi-Sq
 Heads           23         0.5        50         14.58
 Tails           77         0.5        50         14.58

   N  DF  Chi-Sq  P-Value
 100   1   29.16    0.000
```

The only number in this printout that you won't recognize from
my computations above is the `P-value` given as `0.000` (meaning <0.0005).
That is the (very tiny bit) of the area under the density
function of the chi-squared distribution (df = 1) to the right
of 29.16. In general, p-values are obtained from software; you can't usually get accurate p-values from a
printed table.

For what it's worth, Minitab make a pretty bar chart of observed
and expected values, but you can't use such a chart alone to
judge goodness of fit. You need to take the sample size into
account and get the actual value of $Q$ in order to reach a
conclusion. [If we'd tossed the coin 10 times with 2 Heads and 8
Tails, this chart would look much the same, except for the numbers
on the vertical scale, but that result would $not$ lead to rejection of the null hypothesis at the 5% level.]

[image]

Finally, here is the same test in R statistical software. (For the null hypothesis, equal probabilities are assumed, unless unequal ones are supplied.)
Output from R is usually very brief and to the point. By now, you should be able to interpret the output.

```
 chisq.test(c(23,77))

         Chi-squared test for given probabilities

 data:  c(23, 77) 
 X-squared = 29.16, df = 1, p-value = 6.664e-08
```

**Caution about claims when the hypothesis is not rejected.**
If you fail to reject the null hypothesis, you should $not$ say "The coin is fair." 
Perhaps say something like "Results with 100 tosses are consistent with a fair coin." or "Based on 100 tosses, we do not have evidence to claim the coin is biased."

Suppose our 'coin' is really a fair dodecahedral (12-sided) die, with 5 faces marked H and 7 faces marked T.
Then $p = P(Heads) = 5/12,$ not $1/2.$ A simulation shows that in only about 41% of
experiments with 100 'tosses' of this 'coin' would a chi-square test detect unfairness.
However, if there were 4 faces marked H and 8 marked T, for $p = 1/3,$ then about 93% of experiments with 100 trials would detect unfairness. In statistical language the number 41% is called the $power$ of the 100-trial experiment for the alternative value $p = 5/12.$ [We speak of experiments with dice, because [some authors](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/diceRev2.pdf) have shown it may be very
difficult in practice to construct a notably biased coin.]